# SwiftUI: Creating a Custom Transition Animation for NavigationView with Interactive Gestures

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition, gesture, navigationview

I'm working on a SwiftUI project and I'm trying to implement a custom transition animation for the NavigationView when navigating between different views. I want to achieve a unique transition effect that involves interactive gestures.

Specifically, I would like to create a transition animation where, upon swiping from the right edge of the screen, the current view slides out to the left while simultaneously revealing the next view from the right, as if the user is pushing the views in a stack-like manner. The transition should be interactive, allowing the user to pause or cancel the transition mid-swipe.

Could someone please guide me on how to approach this problem? Are there any specific techniques or APIs in SwiftUI that can help me achieve this custom transition animation with interactive gestures?

Any insights, sample code, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

I've explored the built-in transition modifiers in SwiftUI, such as .slide, .move, and .asymmetric, but they don't provide the exact effect I'm looking for. I've also experimented with custom transitions using NavigationView and NavigationLink, but haven't been successful in achieving the desired result. I expected to find a built-in SwiftUI transition modifier or a combination of modifiers that would allow me to achieve the specific transition effect I described. Alternatively, I was hoping to find a way to create a custom transition animation with interactive gestures using SwiftUI's APIs. I haven't been able to find a solution that meets my requirements. The built-in transition modifiers didn't provide the desired effect, and my experimentation with custom transitions didn't yield the expected results.

Comment: I think there's no way currently to do this in pure SwiftUI